# safecracker matrix-menu doesn't appear in overlay

Tags: expressionengine

I have a site, not visible to the public, where I use safecracker and matrix fields in several locations.  On pages that load normally, everything is fine.  But when the matrix fields appear in an overlay (using colorbox), the matrix-menu div isn't created.

Stepping through the code with FireBug, the issue seems to be that the line:

```
var $body = $(document.body);
```

doesn't set $body correctly (maybe this is a race condition for the overlay loading?).  So when it gets to this chunk of code in matrix.js:

```
obj.menu.$ul = $('<ul id="matrix-menu" />').appendTo($body).css({
    opacity: 0,
    display: 'none'
});
```

$body doesn't resolve, so the menu can't attache anywhere.  I think I've fixed it, but want to check and see if I should be worried that I'll break anything else.  If I change the above code to:

```
obj.menu.$ul = $('<ul id="matrix-menu" />').appendTo($(document.body)).css({
    opacity: 0,
    display: 'none'
});
```

everything seems fine.  Is there a better way to address this?

Comment: I too am encountering this issue. We have an EE 2.3.1 site and upgraded Matrix to 2.5.3 and the menu does not show, but when I make the code change above it works fine.

Comment: You need to tag this with "matrix" so the P&T folk see it.

Comment: Actually this should have been posted in http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/ – we’re not actively monitoring any tags on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If the Matrix field doesn’t have a height when it is first initialized, it puts most of its initialization stuff on hold, assuming that it’s either hidden by default or lives on a secondary publish tab. This cuts down on the initial page load time and also fixes some issues with some celltypes (Text, Assets, maybe others.) that need to know the dimensions of DOM elements within their cells.

Matrix will automatically resume its initialization when it has been expanded or its tab has been clicked on, but if you’re using Matrix outside of the Publish page *and* hiding it, you’ll need to trigger that initialization-resuming yourself:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Matrix.instances; i++)
{
    Matrix.instances[i].initRowsIfVisible();
}
```

Comment: I'm actually getting this issue in a normal publish page. I didn't realize the OP was getting it in Safecracker.

Comment: Just realized that you said it’s an EE 2.3 site. Matrix requires EE 2.4 and later (see http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/installation.html). Can you try upgrading EE? If that doesn’t help, please email support@pixelandtonic.com will all the relevant info and we’ll look into it.